# How to query the elastic search using node js client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am new in ElasticSearch. I tried some queries, can anyone please help me to get the unique users for that Audi and BMW keyword?

```js
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "keyword": "Audi"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "keyword": "BMW"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
                "gte": "2019-11-19",
                "lt": "2019-11-29"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

my Index in the elastic search 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2gPh.png)

Need to implement as below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVhH2.png)

Comment: What is your results with your current query and what the expected results? (it would be clearer if you'll write it, and not capturing screenshots)

Comment: You need to run aggregated query. And also to get help with query, you need to post your `elasticsearch` index mappings.

You can get the mappings by `GET your_index/_mapping` and post the result

Comment: @AviadLevy i need the distinct users (uuid) who has bmw or audi in the title.